# Splitting string multiple times in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, lambda

I have a column in a DataFrame that contains a string from which I must retrieve two pieces of information by different separators:

```
ID  STR
280 11040402-38.58551%;11050101-9.29086%;11070101-52.12363%
351 11130203-35%;11130230-65%
510 11070103-69%
655 11090103-41.63463%;11160102-58.36537%
666 11130205-50.00%;11130207-50%
```

I have been trying to use the `.apply` method on this series together with a lambda function to make the splitting in one go, to no avail:

```
df['STR'].apply(lambda x: y.split('-') for y in x.split(';'))
```

Ideally, not only I would be able to split the string in one go, but also separate the left side of the `-` from the right side:

```
ID  STR.LEFT                       STR.RIGHT
280 [11040402, 11050101, 11070101] [38.58551%, 9.29086%, 52.12363%]
351 [11130203, 11130230]           [35%, 65%]
510 [11070103]                     [69%]
655 [11090103, 11160102]           [41.63463%, 58.36537%]
666 [11130205, 11130207]           [50.00%, 50%]
```

I believe this could be achievable with `.apply` and slicing, but any other solution is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try splitting several times:

```
# set ID as index
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)


new_series = df.STR.str.split(';', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=-1,drop=True)

new_df = new_series.str.split('-', expand=True)

new_df.groupby('ID').agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      ID  0                                     1
--  ----  ------------------------------------  --------------------------------------
 0   280  ['11040402', '11050101', '11070101']  ['38.58551%', '9.29086%', '52.12363%']
 1   351  ['11130203', '11130230']              ['35%', '65%']
 2   510  ['11070103']                          ['69%']
 3   655  ['11090103', '11160102']              ['41.63463%', '58.36537%']
 4   666  ['11130205', '11130207']              ['50.00%', '50%']
```

Comment: This solution is not as fast as @pirsquared, but it does another trick for me through the use of `.stack` to break the DataFrame in multiple rows. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

#### `str.split`

Assuming the pattern always leaves `'l-r;l-r;l-r...'`

```
s = df.STR.str.split('-|;')
df[['ID']].join(pd.concat({'STR.LEFT': s.str[::2], 'STR.RIGTH': s.str[1::2]}, axis=1))

    ID                        STR.LEFT                         STR.RIGTH
0  280  [11040402, 11050101, 11070101]  [38.58551%, 9.29086%, 52.12363%]
1  351            [11130203, 11130230]                        [35%, 65%]
2  510                      [11070103]                             [69%]
3  655            [11090103, 11160102]            [41.63463%, 58.36537%]
4  666            [11130205, 11130207]                     [50.00%, 50%]
```

---

If you want to explode these lists into separate rows

```
s = df.STR.str.split('-|;')
i = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(s.str.len() // 2)
d = {'STR.LEFT': np.concatenate(s.str[::2]),
     'STR.RIGHT': np.concatenate(s.str[1::2])}
df[['ID']].iloc[i].assign(**d).reset_index(drop=True)

    ID  STR.LEFT  STR.RIGHT
0  280  11040402  38.58551%
1  280  11050101   9.29086%
2  280  11070101  52.12363%
3  351  11130203        35%
4  351  11130230        65%
5  510  11070103        69%
6  655  11090103  41.63463%
7  655  11160102  58.36537%
8  666  11130205     50.00%
9  666  11130207        50%
```

Comment: This is clearly the fastest of the solutions, at least six times faster than the others. I really like the elegance of building it in just two lines. However, it turned out I also have some need to make the DataFrame split into multiple rows (ID being repeated in this case), which I am able to achieve by using @quang-hoang solution without his last line of code. Pretty good, though! Thanks!

Comment: @mepqfilho that's why specifying your needs in your question are important.  It will be more helpful to a future reader if the answer you've accepted matches what you've asked.  Either way, it isn't a big deal.  I've included some additional code that places the values into separate rows.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

A single [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) call will suffice to extract the pairs into separate columns. You can then aggregate them into lists using `groupby`.

```
(df['STR'].str.extractall(r'(.*?)-(.*?)(?=;|$)')
          .groupby(level=0)
          .agg(list)
          .set_axis(['STR.LEFT', 'STR.RIGHT'], axis=1, inplace=False))

                           STR.LEFT                         STR.RIGHT
0  [11040402, ;11050101, ;11070101]  [38.58551%, 9.29086%, 52.12363%]
1  [11130203, ;11130230]             [35%, 65%]                      
2  [11070103]                        [69%]                           
3  [11090103, ;11160102]             [41.63463%, 58.36537%]          
4  [11130205, ;11130207]             [50.00%, 50%]
```

---

To join with ID, you use just that: `join`.

```
(df['STR'].str.extractall(r'(.*?)-(.*?)(?=;|$)')
          .groupby(level=0)
          .agg(list)
          .set_axis(['STR.LEFT', 'STR.RIGHT'], axis=1, inplace=False)
          .join(df['ID'])

                           STR.LEFT                         STR.RIGHT   ID
0  [11040402, ;11050101, ;11070101]  [38.58551%, 9.29086%, 52.12363%]  280
1  [11130203, ;11130230]             [35%, 65%]                        351
2  [11070103]                        [69%]                             510
3  [11090103, ;11160102]             [41.63463%, 58.36537%]            655
4  [11130205, ;11130207]             [50.00%, 50%]                     666
```

Comment: This is an acceptable solution, but the `.extractall` method seems to keep the `;` as part of the string, which is preferably free of it.